# Interrupting boost python C++ routine

Tags: python, c++, boost, copy-paste

I have written an application with PyQt5 for Windows and I have C++ modules embedded with boost python. One of my C++ routines performs an optimization. It can happen that an optimization does not converge. In that case, I would like to have a possibility to interrupt the routine rather than wait until the max iterations are exceeded. So I need a way to catch Ctrl-C inside the C++ routine so that I can take corresponding action. How can I catch Ctrl-C in this case?

Comment: Ctrl-C triggers a SIGINT signal in Linux, I'd expect something equivalent in Windows.

Comment: The question then is how do I route the signal through Python down to the running C++ code?

Comment: You don’t: you temporarily **override** its handling of the interrupt during your routine.

Comment: Thanks, Davis, that was easier than expected. Once I disable signal Python's signal handling, it works just as if I was running a C++ program. Thanks.